# Amending commit in history with merges without flattening it

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-history-rewrite

Lets say I have a history similar to this.
Develop is periodically merged into master.

```
a---b---c---d---i---j---k---o  master
 \             /           /
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n    develop
```

How to I amend b without completely flattening the history?
If I interactively rebase, and amend b, I'll end up with a history looking like this:

(upper case signifies that the commit changed)

```
a---B---C---E---F---G---H---J---K---L---M---N  master
 \
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n                    develop
```

How can I retain history structure, and have it look like this instead:

```
a---B---C---D---I---J---K---O  master
 \             /           /
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n    develop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you cannot change anything about any existing commit.

What this means is that to "change" `b` to `B`, you do in fact have to make a new-and-improved `B`.  The old `b` will continue to exist (for how long, is another question entirely).  Regular `git rebase`, interactive or not, works by copying the commits to new-and-improved ones.  Regular rebase also *removes* merges and flattens, as you noted.

Since Git 2.18, `git rebase` has had a mode called `--rebase-merges`.  This retains merges—or more accurately, re-*creates* them as new merge commits, by literally running `git merge` again.  Pre-2.18, `git rebase` has `-p`, which uses the interactive rebase machinery and otherwise preserves merges (by repeating them) as well.  It's somewhat defective compared to the fancier new version, but—I think (have not tested!)—should work for this case.

Hence, use `git rebase -i --rebase-merges` the way you would use `git rebase -i`.  If you lack the `--rebase-merges`, update your Git version, or use `git rebase  -i -p` and be very careful not to disturb the order of the various operations, or build your new chain by hand.

To build it by hand, run `git checkout` on commit `B`.  You can assign a new branch name here, if you like, or just do the whole operation with a detached `HEAD` the way `git rebase` would:

```
git checkout -b temp-rebuild <hash-of-b>
```

to use a new temporary branch name, for instance.  Then use `git commit --amend` (perhaps with additional stuff first) to make your new `B`:

```
  B   <-- temp-rebuild
 /
a---b---c---d---i---j---k---o   <-- master
 \             /           /
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n   <-- develop
```

Now run `git cherry-pick` on the hash of commit `c` to copy it to new commit `C`, and repeat for `d`:

```
  B---C---D   <-- temp-rebuild
 /
a---b---c---d---i---j---k---o   <-- master
 \             /           /
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n   <-- develop
```

Now run `git merge` on the hash of commit `h`, `i`'s *second* parent, to make new merge `I`, resolving any merge conflicts if needed:

```
  B---C---D------I   <-- temp-rebuild
 /              /
a---b---c---d--/i---j---k---o   <-- master
 \            |/           /
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n   <-- develop
```

Use more cherry-pick and merge commands to complete the process:

```
  B---C---D------I---J---K--O   <-- temp-rebuild
 /              /          /
a---b---c---d--/i---j---k-|-o   <-- master
 \            |/          |/
  e---f---g---h---l---m---n   <-- develop
```

Now that the new commits are built, force the name `master` to point to the final commit, and stop drawing the old `b-c-d-i-j-k-o` chain, and you have what you wanted.  This is what `git rebase --rebase-merges` and `git rebase -p` do: `-p` just uses a fragile algorithm that , while `--rebase-merges` uses a new interactive instruction sheet format, that lets you specify the new graph in a way that doesn't break when you move commits around.